# cl.exe is taking a long time during InvokeCompilerPassW

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I've got a CMake project that I'm building with Linux and Windows. The project automatically generates packages using CPack, and when I build with

`cmake --build . --config Release --target package`,

a full compilation is triggered. On Linux, this full compilation (about 10k lines of C) takes about 1 minute from a clean slate. On Windows, it takes 25 minutes or more.

I booted up Process Explorer, and found this:

[image: cl.exe slowdown stack trace]

[image: cl.exe slowdown cpu time]

I may be interpreting this wrong, but it looks like `o_strcat_s` is pegging over 10% of my CPU time. String concatenation should be linear time, but it looks like each pass is having to reallocate more and more memory to achieve the concatenation (see `RtlReAllocateHeap`). Why is this? What's making `cl.exe` run so slow when invoked from the command line like this?

I'm using Visual Studio generators, if that helps.

Comment: While a bit late to the party, try to pass compiler option `/Bt` to MSVC. Better yet, use the undocumented `/d2cgsummary` optimizer option, that will display timing statistics for individual functions. See https://aras-p.info/blog/2017/10/23/Best-unknown-MSVC-flag-d2cgsummary/ Then you might want to disable optimization of some too complex functions with `#pragma optimize( "", off )`